# Prove implication all Cauchy sequences have a limit $\to$ all monotone increasing bounded above sequences converge$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

So, we assume that all Cauchy sequences converge. How can we deduce ''all monotone bounded above increasing sequences converge'' from that?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $a_n$ is monotone bounded above prove prove that it is Cauchy.

**Hint 2:** If you are familiar with the supremum, that give you the $N$ for each $\epsilon$.

If not prove it by contradiction.

As you said $\exists \epsilon$ such that for all $N$ there exist $m,n>N$ with $|x_n-x_m|>\epsilon$.

Construct inductively $x_{k_n}$ a subsequence so that $x_{k_n} \geq x_{k_1}+(n-1)\epsilon$.

$P(1)$ is trivial. For the inductive step, pick $N=k_n$. Then you can find $m_1> m_2> N$ such that 
$$
|x_{m_1}-x_{m_2}| > \epsilon
$$
As the sequence is increasing, we have
$$
x_{m_1} \geq x_{m_2}+ \epsilon \geq x_N+ \epsilon= x_{k_n}+\epsilon
$$ 
So pick $k_{n+1}=m_1$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite got the second idea(prove it by contradiction ). We assume that it is not Cauchy. Then $\exists  \epsilon > 0$ where $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $n$ and $m$ greater than $N$ such that $|x_m-x_n|>\epsilon$. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Jxt921 There was a mistake in the second hint, fixed it with enough details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $M$ the least upperbound of an increasing bounded sequence $(u_n)$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, here is a term $u_{n_0}$ in the sequence that is within $\varepsilon$ of $M$. For all $n>n_0$, we have $\;u_{n_0}<u_n\le M$.